# glTF models are red in sceneform

Tags: gltf, sceneform, 3d-modelling

So I have some gltf models I generated and have uploaded them to a url to load them at runtime within Sceneform. When I open the models on windows, it looks great, but when I try to place the objects within Sceneform the models become red. I am unsure why this is happening and would appreciate any pointers.

Object opened in 3D Viewer
[image]

Object when placed in Sceneform
[image]

The jellyfish gltf model example in case those got corrupted somehow: [GLTF Model](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jayleenli/AR-Sandbox-Aquarium-gltf-obj-dump/d84f2b0d1612c322510362c95c649495baefc557/jellyfish.gltf)

.bin file is here, however I don't think looking at this will help much: [GLTF .bin](https://github.com/jayleenli/AR-Sandbox-Aquarium-gltf-obj-dump/blob/d84f2b0d1612c322510362c95c649495baefc557/jellyfish.bin)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the sceneform code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue was due to a malformed glTF file. You can use Kronos' glTF online validator at this link.
https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/

In case anyone is having the same issue, make sure the file is not malformed or try using a different file format like GLB.